# How do I get the value of Heart Rate Measurement from a Polar H10 in iOS using Swift and Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, gatt

I am using Polar H10 as a heart rate monitor and I would like to get the values that are in the Heart Rate Measurement Characteristic in iOS using Swift and Core Bluetooth.

Here is the code in the appropriate callback method of the CBPeripheralDelegate:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    print("didUpdateValueFor")

    if let error = error {
        print("error:", error)
    }

    guard let value = characteristic.value else {
        return
    }

    print("value:", value)

    guard let stringValue = String(data: value, encoding: .utf8) else {
        return
    }

    print("string value:", stringValue)

}
```

The official Bluetooth web page for this [Heart Rate Measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) shows this unformatted information:

> Mandatory 8bit Note: The format of the Heart Rate Measurement Value field is dependent upon bit 0 of the Flags field. C1 uint8 org.bluetooth.unit.period.beats_per_minute Note: The format of the Heart Rate Measurement Value field is dependent upon bit 0 of the Flags field. C2 uint16 org.bluetooth.unit.period.beats_per_minute The presence of the Energy Expended field is dependent upon bit 3 of the Flags field. C3 uint16 org.bluetooth.unit.energy.joule C4 uint16 org.bluetooth.unit.time.second Resolution of 1/1024 second The fields in the above table are in the order of LSO to MSO. Where LSO = Least Significant Octet and MSO = Most Significant Octet.

I can't figure out what the documentation means. Particularly I don't understand what C1, C2, C3 and C4 refer to.

The characteristic.value is type Data. What do I do with that Data object? How do I get the values I need? I firstly want the RR value.

There are similar posts like this, but they don't help me because they are using different tools and a different language, or they don't have good answers.

Update:

I since figured out that the page at [Heart Rate Measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) is an xml file. I was able to get the information I need from that file after I open it with an app that could show it. The first time I looked at it was in Safari. It does not show xml files well. Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 2011 Bluetooth SIG, Inc. All rights reserved. -->
<Characteristic xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schemas.bluetooth.org/Documents/characteristic.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement" uuid="2A37" name="Heart Rate Measurement">
    <InformativeText>
    </InformativeText>
    <Value>
        <Field name="Flags">
            <Requirement>Mandatory</Requirement>
            <Format>8bit</Format>

            <BitField>
                <Bit index="0" size="1" name="Heart Rate Value Format bit">
                    <Enumerations>
                        <Enumeration key="0" value="Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT8. Units: beats per minute (bpm)" requires="C1" />
                        <Enumeration key="1" value="Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT16. Units: beats per minute (bpm)" requires="C2" />
                    </Enumerations>
                </Bit>
                <Bit index="1" size="2" name="Sensor Contact Status bits">
                    <Enumerations>
                        <Enumeration key="0" value="Sensor Contact feature is not supported in the current connection" />
                        <Enumeration key="1" value="Sensor Contact feature is not supported in the current connection" />
                        <Enumeration key="2" value="Sensor Contact feature is supported, but contact is not detected" />
                        <Enumeration key="3" value="Sensor Contact feature is supported and contact is detected" />
                    </Enumerations>
                </Bit>

                <Bit index="3" size="1" name="Energy Expended Status bit">
                    <Enumerations>
                        <Enumeration key="0" value="Energy Expended field is not present" />
                        <Enumeration key="1" value="Energy Expended field is present. Units: kilo Joules" requires="C3"/>
                    </Enumerations>
                </Bit>
                <Bit index="4" size="1" name="RR-Interval bit">
                    <Enumerations>
                        <Enumeration key="0" value="RR-Interval values are not present." />
                        <Enumeration key="1" value="One or more RR-Interval values are present." requires="C4"/>
                        </Enumerations>
                </Bit>
                <ReservedForFutureUse index="5" size="3"></ReservedForFutureUse>
                </BitField>
        </Field>
        <Field name="Heart Rate Measurement Value (uint8)">
              <InformativeText>
                Note: The format of the Heart Rate Measurement Value field is dependent upon bit 0 of the Flags field.
              </InformativeText>
            <Requirement>C1</Requirement>
            <Format>uint8</Format>
            <Unit>org.bluetooth.unit.period.beats_per_minute</Unit>

        </Field>    

         <Field name="Heart Rate Measurement Value (uint16)">
              <InformativeText>
                Note: The format of the Heart Rate Measurement Value field is dependent upon bit 0 of the Flags field.
              </InformativeText>
            <Requirement>C2</Requirement>
            <Format>uint16</Format>
            <Unit>org.bluetooth.unit.period.beats_per_minute</Unit>

        </Field>       

        <Field name="Energy Expended">
            <InformativeText>The presence of the Energy Expended field is dependent upon bit 3 of the Flags field.</InformativeText>
            <Requirement>C3</Requirement>
            <Format>uint16</Format>
            <Unit>org.bluetooth.unit.energy.joule</Unit>

        </Field>
        <Field name="RR-Interval">
            <InformativeText>
               <!-- The presence of the RR-Interval field is dependent upon bit 4 of the Flags field. 
                <p>The RR-Interval value represents the time between two R-Wave detections.</p> 

                <p>Because several RR-Intervals may be measured between transmissions of the HEART RATE MEASUREMENT characteristic, 
                multiple RR-Interval sub-fields may be present in the characteristic. The number of RR-Interval sub-fields present 
                is determined by a combination of the overall length of the characteristic and whether or not the characteristic contains 
                the Energy Expended field.</p>

                <p>Where there are multiple RR-Interval values transmitted in the HEART RATE MEASUREMENT characteristic, the field uses the following format:</p>
                <p>RR-Interval Value 0 (LSO...MSO), RR-Interval Value 1 (LSO...MSO), RR-Interval Value 2 (LSO...MSO), RR-Interval Value n (LSO...MSO).</p>
                <p>Where the RR-Interval Value 0 is older than the RR-Interval Value 1.</p>
                <p>RR-Interval Value 0 is transmitted first followed by the newer measurements.</p>-->

            </InformativeText>
            <Requirement>C4</Requirement>
            <Format>uint16</Format>
            <Unit>org.bluetooth.unit.time.second</Unit>
            <Description>Resolution of 1/1024 second</Description>



        </Field>
    </Value>
   <Note> <p>The fields in the above table are in the order of LSO to MSO. Where LSO = Least Significant Octet and MSO = Most Significant Octet.</p>
   </Note>
</Characteristic>
```

Comment: There is more information [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=239865) but essentially your data is a series of 8 bit bytes.  Some of the bits in those bytes tell you how to interpret the other bytes.  The first thing you would want to do is convert your data to an array of `UInt8`. [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor) will probably help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my working solution to get the RR-Interval:

```
guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return nil }
        let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)
        var rawRRinterval = 0
        //if fifth bit (index 4) is set -> RR-Inteval present (00010000 = 16)
        if (byteArray[0] & 16)  != 0{
            print("One or more RR-Interval values are present.")
            //00000000 (0) = heart rate 8 bit in [1]
        //00000001 (1) = heart rate 16 bit in [1] + [2]
        //00000110 () = sensor contact flags - status decoded in flags no other field needed
        //00001000 (8) = energy status 16 bit in [2] + [3]
        //00001001 (9) = energy status 16 bit in [3] + [4]
        
        //00010000 (16) = RR-value 16 bit in [2] + [3]
        //00010010 (18) = RR-value 16 bit in [2] + [3]
        //00010100 (20) = RR-value 16 bit in [2] + [3]
        //00010110 (22) = RR-value 16 bit in [2] + [3]
        
        //00010001 (17) = RR-value 16 bit in [3] + [4]
        //00010011 (19) = RR-value 16 bit in [3] + [4]
        //00010101 (21) = RR-value 16 bit in [3] + [4]
        //00010111 (23) = RR-value 16 bit in [3] + [4]
        
        //00011000 (24) = RR-value 16 bit in [4] + [5]
        //00011010 (26) = RR-value 16 bit in [4] + [5]
        //00011100 (28) = RR-value 16 bit in [4] + [5]
        //00011110 (30) = RR-value 16 bit in [4] + [5]
        
        //00011001 (25) = RR-value 16 bit in [5] + [6]
        //00011011 (27) = RR-value 16 bit in [5] + [6]
        //00011101 (29) = RR-value 16 bit in [5] + [6]
        //00011111 (31) = RR-value 16 bit in [5] + [6]
        
        switch byteArray[0] {
        case 16,18,20,22:
            //rr-value in [2] und [3]
            rawRRinterval = Int(byteArray[2]) + (Int(byteArray[3]) << 8)
        case 17,19,21,23:
            //rr-value in [3] und [4]
            rawRRinterval = Int(byteArray[3]) + (Int(byteArray[4]) << 8)
        case 24,26,28,30:
            //rr-value in [4] und [5]
            rawRRinterval = Int(byteArray[4]) + (Int(byteArray[5]) << 8)
        case 25,27,29,31:
            //rr-value in [5] und [6]
            rawRRinterval = Int(byteArray[4]) + (Int(byteArray[5]) << 8)
        }else{
             print("RR-Interval values are not present.")
        }
        
        //Resolution of 1/1024 second
        let rrInSeconds: Double = Double(rawRRinterval)/1024
        print(" rrInSeconds: \(rrInSeconds)")
        let rrInMilSeconds: Double = Double(rrInSeconds) * 1000
        print(" rrInMilSeconds: \(rrInMilSeconds)")
        
        let value = (Double(rawRRinterval) / 1024.0 ) * 1000.0
        print(" value: \(value)")
        
        return rrInMilSeconds
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my function for getting HR as well as HRV (RR-Intervals) from BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy) connection to an iOS App. Unlike the solution from @yedy, I wanted to "pop" my array as I go along it.

```
 private func heartRate2(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> (Int, [Double]) {
    guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return (-1, []) }
    var byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)
    var rawRRinterval = 0
    var rrInMilSeconds = [Double]()
    var hrValue = 0
        
    // https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/62692067/14414215
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458794/14414215
    // Refer section 3.103.2.1 Flags field of Bluetooth GATT Specification Supplement
    // The heart rate mesurement is in the 2nd, or in the 2nd and 3rd bytes, i.e. one one or in two bytes
    // The first byte of the first bit specifies the length of the heart rate data, 0 == 1 byte, 1 == 2 bytes
    // the & 0x01 is the bitwise operation on the first value in the array. (the Flag)
    // BIT0: 00000001 - 1   - 0x01 - HR Value 0 = UINT8, 1 = UINT16
    // BIT1: 00000010 - 2   - 0x02 - Sensor Contact Status 1 = Sensor Contact Supported
    // BIT2: 00000100 - 4   - 0x04 - Sensor Contact Status 1 = Good contact with the skin
    // BIT3: 00001000 - 8   - 0x08 - Energy Expended 1 = Present
    // BIT4: 00010000 - 16  - 0x10 - RR-Interval 1 = Present

    let flags = byteArray[0]
    
    // Pop 1st Bits (Flags)
    byteArray.removeFirst(1)

    // Check HR is UINT8(1bit) or UINT16(2bit)
    if flags & 0x01 == 0 {
      hrValue = Int(byteArray[0])
      byteArray.removeFirst(1)
    } else if flags & 0x01 == 1 {
      hrValue = (Int(byteArray[0]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[1])
      byteArray.removeFirst(2)
    }
    
    // Check Sensor Contact Detection support
    if flags & 0x02 > 0 {
      byteArray.removeFirst(1)
    }

    // Check Sensor Contact Support
    if flags & 0x04 > 0 {
      byteArray.removeFirst(1)
    }

    // Check Energy Expended Support
    if flag & 0x08 > 0 {
      byteArray.removeFirst(2)
    }

    // check for RR presence
    if (flags & 0x10 )  != 0 {
      while byteArray.count > 0 {
        rawRRinterval = Int(byteArray[0]) + (Int(byteArray[1]) << 8)
        
        //Resolution of 1/1024 second
        rrInMilSeconds.append((Double(rawRRinterval) / 1024.0 ) * 1000.0)
        byteArray.removeFirst(2)
      }
    }
    
    return (hrValue, rrInMilSeconds)
  }
```

Comment: What does "BLE" stand for?

Comment: @DanielBrower ```BLE = Bluetooth Low Energy```, some also calls it as ```BTLE - Bluetooth Low Energy```

Comment: Is the if flag & 0x08 supposed to be something different?

Comment: @Ryan you are right. There was a missing operator there. Have edited my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to convert the characteristic value data to the `UInt8` array then you need to check that your heart rate sensor is providing value at which index. I am using the following code in my project and it is working fine. Hope it will help you too.

```
var heartRate: Int = 0
guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return }
let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)
let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
if firstBitValue == 0 {
    // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd byte
    heartRate = Int(byteArray[1])
} else {
    // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd and 3rd bytes
    heartRate = (Int(byteArray[2]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[1])
}
print("heart rate", heartRate)
```

Put the above code in the `didUpdateValueFor` method of the `CBPeripheralDelegate` and try to get value from your heart rate sensor.

Comment: How did you figure out that a 0 in the first bit value of the first byte means the second byte is the heart rate value? Were you able to figure that out from the official bluetooth.com web page for the heart rate measurement characteristic that I included in my post? I couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: Yes you're correct. it's from the XML you posted. Note that it says ```Bit Index=0``` that means Look at the first bit from the flags field ```byteArray[0]```, then you have the ```enumerations keys``` , if it's (the first bit) 0 then it's an 8 bit integer, else it's 16bit integer. @yedy's answer above show how to decode it