# Heart Rate Value in BLE

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am having a hard time getting a valid value out of the HR characteristics.  I am clearly not handling the values properly in Dart.

Example Data:

```
List<int> value = [22, 56, 55, 4, 7, 3];
```

**Flags Field:**
I convert the first item in the main byte array to binary to get the flags

```
22 = 10110 (as binary)
```

this leads me to believe that it is U16 (bit[0] is == 1)

**HR Value:**

Because it is 16 bit I am trying to get the bytes in the 1 & 2 indexes.  I then try to buffer them into a ByteData.  From there I get convert them to Uint16 with the Endian set to Little.  This is giving me a value of 14136.  Clearly I am missing something fundamental about how this is supposed to work.

Any help in clearing up what I am not understanding about how to process the 16 bit BLE values would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

```
  /*
Constructor - constructs the heart rate value from a BLE message
 */
  HeartRate(List<int> values) {
    var flags = values[0];
    var s = flags.toRadixString(2);
    List<String> flagsArray = s.split("");

    int offset = 0;

    //Determine whether it is U16 or not
    if (flagsArray[0] == "0") {
      //Since it is Uint8 i will only get the first value
      var hr = values[1];
      print(hr);
    } else {
      //Since UTF 16 is two bytes I need to combine them
      //Create a buffer with the first two bytes after the flags
      var buffer = new Uint8List.fromList(values.sublist(1, 3)).buffer;
      var hrBuffer = new ByteData.view(buffer);
      var hr = hrBuffer.getUint16(0, Endian.little);
      print(hr);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This data is the wrong length. If you're reading org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement, the payload should be between 2 and 5 bytes long (unless there's RR, which I don't see here), depending on the flags. So I strongly suspect you're creating `value` incorrectly. Note that bits are counted from the LSB, not the MSB (so you're reading them backwards). BLE is also always little-endian, so you need to shift your second byte over 8 bits if when you do read a uint16. But let's start with where you're getting your data, because it looks wrong.

Comment: Thank you Rob - I appreciate the response.   It is possible that I am getting the data incorrectly (new to much of this) but I am getting it from the "flutter_blue" example project.  This is what is printing to the screen when I pull the characteristic (0x2A37). 

Here is another one that is much shorter (that could be more reliable)  [22, 56, 55, 4, 7, 3]

Given that the bits are LSB then does that mean that the 8vs16 bit is actually 0 in my example?  

I added the full list to the OP.   Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your updated data looks much better. Here's how to decode it, and the process you'd use to figure this out yourself from scratch.

### Determine the format

The [Bluetooth](https://bluetooth.com) site has been reorganized recently (~2020), and in particular they got rid of some of the document viewers, which makes things much harder to find and read IMO. All the documentation is in the [Heart Rate Service](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=239866) (HRS) document, linked from the main [GATT page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/), but for just parsing the format, the best source I know of is the XML for [org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml). (Since the reorganization, I don't know how you can find this page without searching for it. It doesn't seem to be linked anymore.)

### Byte 0 - Flags: 22 (0001 0110)

Bits are numbered from LSB (0) to MSB (7).

- Bit 0 - Heart Rate Value Format: 0 => UINT8 beats per minute
- Bit 1-2 - Sensor Contact Status: 11 => Supported and detected
- Bit 3 - Energy Expended Status: 0 => Not present
- Bit 4 - RR-Interval: 1 => One or more values are present

The meaning of RR-intervals is explained in the HRS document, linked above. It sounds like you just want the heart rate value, so I won't go into them here.

### Byte 1 - UINT8 BPM: 56

Since Bit 0 of flags was 0, this is the beats per minute. 56.

### Bytes 2-5 - UINT16 RR Intervals: 55, 4, 7, 3

You probably don't care about these, but there are two UINT16 values here (there can be an arbitrary number of RR-Interval values). BLE is always little-endian, so [55, 4] is 1,079 (55 + 4<<8), and [7, 3] is 775 (7 + 3<<8).

I believe the docs are a little confusing on this one. The XML suggests that these values are in seconds, but the comments say "Resolution of 1/1024 second." The normal way to express this would be `<BinaryExponent>-10</BinaryExponent>`, and I'm certain that's what they meant. So these would be:

- RR0: 1.05s (1079/1024)
- RR1: 0.76s (775/1024)

Comment: Rob - I truly appreciate the time that you took to clearly explain this and you are right!   The documentation isn't nearly as clear as this.   Thank you so much!

And so just so I know that I am 100% clear...   If the first flag was a 1 then I would do the exact same logic to get the BPM?  

hr = (values[1] + values[2] << 8  

Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know how common that would be outside of medical devices (since 8 bits will get you 255 bpm, at which point I hope a doctor is involved), but it's certainly possible you'd run into it.

Comment: Hi @RobNapier I still don't get it how to interpret the heart rate value in Byte 1. As the value increases it runs into negative values like 126, 127, -127, -126, -125,... I raised a question on this topic. Maybe you can bring some light in this. Thanks! -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024800/ble-heart-rate-senser-value-interpretation

Comment: @Emanuel UINT8 mean 8 bit unsigned integer so if you see negative values then that just means you've cast it to a signed integer data type. Ensure you're using an unsigned int.

Comment: I'm trying to make a companion app for my smartwatch. I'm trying to get heart rate and bpm through the device. I don't know what and where to start. If any of you would please be willing to help, it would be great.