# How to fetch heart rate from fireboltt smartwatch to flutter android app

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a flutter app to fetch data(heart rate, spo2,......) from my smartwatch. I don't know if it is wearOS or tizen or anything. It is smartwatch of the brand fire boltt. I'm currently using flutter_ble for bluetooth functionality. I'm getting services and characteristics from bluetooth client. But can't figure out which of those data corresponds to what. How am I supposed to tackle this?

This is one example of data I am receiving:

```
BluetoothService{uuid: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 
deviceId: F9:CE:08:3E:0B:31, 
isPrimary: true, 
characteristics: [BluetoothCharacteristic{
    uuid: 00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 
    deviceId: F9:CE:08:3E:0B:31, 
    serviceUuid: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 
    secondaryServiceUuid: null,
    properties: CharacteristicProperties{
        broadcast: false, 
        read: true, 
        writeWithoutResponse: false,
        write: false, 
        notify: true, 
        indicate: false, 
        authenticatedSignedWrites: false, 
        extendedProperties: false, 
        notifyEncryptionRequired: false, 
        indicateEncryptionRequired: false}, 
    descriptors: [BluetoothDescriptor{
        uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 
        deviceId: F9:CE:08:3E:0B:31, 
        serviceUuid: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 
        characteristicUuid: 00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, 
        value: []}],
    value: []], 
includedServices: []}
```

Comment: Can you add the result that you are receiving?

Comment: I would assume you'd want 0x1822 (Pulse Oximeter) and 0x180D (Heart Rate) for this. This page will then have the specifications for each: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/  Use the documents labeled "service" not "profile" (HRS and PLXS). The Bluetooth site is a little confusing at times. The doc you want is the *specification* not the test suite. You'll find it as a "Download Now" button on the relevant pages. For example: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/pulse-oximeter-service-1-0-1/

Comment: When you download the 31 page spec for SPO2, you're likely to be overwhelmed. That's normal; do not worry. Skim it; see what makes sense and what doesn't, and then take this one step at a time. Start with Heart Rate because you'll probably find tutorials for that (and you've already found SO answers to how to parse it conceptually, if not in actual code). Once you have some data and code, start asking questions for each step. That's where SO helps best: focused question with unambiguous answer. SO unfortunately stumbles on open-ended questions. Bluetooth is in fact hard, but you can do it.

Comment: Is your app working?Is your source code available somewhere?

Comment: @RobNapier i just have one more question. Now that I know that I want heart rate i.e. 0x180d. But the data I'm receiving is like above. How am I supposed to match which one and how to take the value.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458794/97337

Comment: @RobNapier thank you so much, that answer genuinely helped a lot

Comment: @SimranSharma have you got access the fire boultt dat? please let me or any sample. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the device supports standard services and characteristics here is the list of bluetooth UUID: [16-bit UUID Numbers
Document](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf).

Easy way to inspect which services the device supports is to use bluetooth internals, `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices`,

Comment: @ukBaz Can you help me, I want to know if Fireboltt watch supports standard Services and Characteristics?

Comment: Can you help me, I want to know if Fireboltt watch supports standard Services and Characteristics?

Comment: @SimranSharma Can you help me, I want to know if Fireboltt watch supports standard Services and Characteristics?